# How do I return a reference to something owned and alive?

Tags: rust

How do I correctly return a reference in the set function in the following code? I do understand that the variable `set` goes out of scope when the block ends, but the array it is referencing is owned and alive. The attempt with the lifetime `'b` was futile.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct Appearance<'a> {
    identity:   &'a u64, 
    role:       &'a str
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
enum Dereference<'a> {
    Dereference1ary {set: [&'a Appearance<'a>;1]},
    Dereference2ary {set: [&'a Appearance<'a>;2]},
}
impl<'a, 'b> Dereference<'a> {
    fn set(&self) -> &'b [&'a Appearance<'a>] {
        match *self {
            Dereference::Dereference1ary{set} => &set,
            Dereference::Dereference2ary{set} => &set
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = "hair_color";
    let i1 = 42;
    let i2 = 43;
    let a1 = Appearance{identity: &i1, role: r};
    let a2 = Appearance{identity: &i2, role: r};
    let d1 = Dereference::Dereference1ary{set: [&a1]};
    let d2 = Dereference::Dereference2ary{set: [&a1, &a2]};
    let list: Vec<Dereference> = vec!(d1, d2);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    println!("{:?}", d1.set());
}
```

There is a playground set up here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd528ebd054a9ce96004c8608166f9ac&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `Derefencece1ary{set}` copies `set` and takes a reference to the copy. What you want is to reference the `set` field directly, by using `Dereference1ary{ ref set }`

```
impl<'a> Dereference<'a> {
    fn set(&self) -> &[&'a Appearance<'a>] {
        match *self {
            Dereference::Dereference1ary{ref set} => set,
            Dereference::Dereference2ary{ref set} => set,
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your lifetime `'b` is superfluous, but if you want it explicitly, you can write

```
fn set<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b [&'a Appearance<'a>]
```

because you want to borrow a part of the `self` object, so the lifetimes need to match.

Comment: Thank you, the ref keyword is exactly what I was looking for and was yet to learn :)